# Is there a way to embed applied CSS within a URL?

Tags: css, url

Is there a way to embed CSS within a URL?

My intent is to provide a URL to my users that formats content--it's pretty simple CSS to accomplish my goal.  Can this be done and, if so, how?

Comment: no it's not possible, you need a server side logic or JS

Comment: @TemaniAfif, that's what I assumed but I was hoping I was wrong.